# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?' Problem for run my next application

Tags: next.js

I have a next application and when I want run this with 'npx next start', this don't run and returned this error :

```
rojects\Shamym-yas-novin\.env.local
C:\projects\Shamym-yas-novin\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:1046
            env: pageInfo.env ?? [],
                               ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
```

How can I fix it?

I just try run my next application but this field!

node.js v13.14.0
npm v6.14.4
Next.js v13.0.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem just was inside the node.js version!

when I change my node.js version to 16.6.0 this got ok!

soo, I hope this will can be help someone.